# Remove multiple space in between string to a single space

Tags: mysql

Trying to clean up string data. TRIM removed leading and trailing spaces. Using REPLACE as REPLACE (col_name," ","") removed all spaces. Need a solution that will result in expected output.
Sample data:
`7136 South Yale #300                       Tulsa,;Oklahoma` 
`428 NW 10th St.                                 OKC` 
`2903 W. Britton Road                       OKC`

Expected output :
`7136 South Yale #300 Tulsa,;Oklahoma` 
`428 NW 10th St. OKC` 
`2903 W. Britton Road OKC`

I use MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MySQL 8+ we could just have done a regex replacement on `\s{2,}` and replaced with a single space.  On 5.7 this is a bit harder.  Assuming that each address would only have at most *one* block of two or more unwanted spaces in it, we use substring operations here:

```sql
SELECT address,
       CASE WHEN address LIKE '%  %'
            THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(address, 1, INSTR(address, '  ') - 1), ' ',
                        LTRIM(SUBSTRING(address, INSTR(address, '  '))))
            ELSE address END AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

The above logic uses an `INSTR()` trick to find the start of the block of two or more spaces.  It generates the output address by piecing together the two substrings on either side of this block, with excess spaces removed.